# Returning Colored HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to have my Google App Script return HTML that is colored based on a call to Google Calendar. Basically a green "Available" if there are no events on calendar and a red "Unavailable" if there are events.

```
function getavail(instr) {
  var today = new Date();
  var scriptProperties=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var instrcal= scriptProperties.getProperty(instr);
  var event=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(instrcal).getEventsForDay(today);
  if (event<1) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<font color="#00cc00">Available</font>')
    }
  else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput.('<font color="#ff0000">Unavailable</font>') ;
    }
}
```

In the page HTML, I am calling function getavail through a scriplet

```
<?= getavail('instr') ?>
```

And for some reason, it renders like this instead...

```
EXPLORER (2386): HtmlOutput
```

Any help would be much appreciated. For reference I was using the example from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Edited and replaced with text

Comment: It's an object of class HtmlOutput. Do you want the result of getContent? What happens with the return value?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the output to appear as colored HTML text. I output the return value directly to the HTML by using a scriplet (<?= >). I tried using getContent( ) as well, but it shows up on the page as <font color= hex>'string'</font> and not as 'string' (colored).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return your `html` as a string in your `getavail()`, then using a [force-printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) with the syntax `<?!= ... ?>` will do the trick.

Also note that the [getEventsForDay()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsfordaydate) returns an Array of events, so to get the number of events you need to check the `length`

Here's an example:

```
function getavail() {
  var today = new Date();
  var calendarId = "{YOUR_CALENDAR_ID}";

  var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventsForDay(today);

  if (events.length < 1) {
    return '<font color="#00cc00">Available</font>';
  }else {
    return '<font color="#ff0000">Unavailable</font>';
  }
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<?!= getavail() ?>
```